Can SQLITE database files used for attacking?
I'm implementing a client to a web service that offers multiple download options - CSV, JSON, Parquet and SQLITE ".db". The response data set has a small number of tabular data sets. SQLite is a good fit, as it eliminates the need to upload the individual tabular data set into a database for efficient join queries.
I'm concerned about protecting against insufficient data from the service.
Technically, is it possible to trigger attack on programs that read the SQLITE database (from embedding a virus)? I believe CSV, JSON, and the parquet can be read safely (most parsers will handle buffer overflows, nulls, etc.). The SQLite database is much more complex. Can it carry and force execution of malicious code on readers? I intend to open the file RO and only do a select statement from a Python client.
For reference: The SQLite site security page discusses some of those questions.

For the purposes of your question, can we assume you've applied all the recommendations from SQLite Defense Against The Dark Arts?

You're assumption that there is such thing as a safe file format is wrong: CSV: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-13421, JSON: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2023-23088, parquet: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2023-47248

@Schwern - Yes. I'm trying to "prove" to the security team that I've taken all reasonable required actions to protect against malicious payload arriving from the service.

@user1937198. I'm trying to separate parsing issues vs format issue. Shell script is unlikely to be a safe file format, as it can contain executable commands.. Same for Excel spreadsheet with embedded VBA macro - execution in unsafe. The question is if reading a specific format REQUIRE execution of arbitrary code. For CSV, JSON and Parquet - I believe that answer is no.

@user1937198 Those are all bugs in specific implementations. If we're going to get into implementation bugs then nothing counts as safe. The OP is asking for security issues inherent in the format and if there are ways to mitigate them. "Download and run this shell script" vs "download and read this text file".
